# Virtual scroll in angular 6 with material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, virtualscroll

I wanna use a virtual scroll with the angular material table.
and I don't want to use pagination function.
my code is like below.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="psa_invoice_number">
          <mat-header-cell [style.flex]="'0 0 10%'" *matHeaderCellDef><span> INV NO. </span></mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span> {{element.psa_invoice_number}} </span>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row  *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
```